# Alternative to "manned" when referring to an extraterrestrial spacecraft?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

In [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/52605/18252)  about manned spaceships versus drones, a user (perhaps jokingly) [pointed out](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/52605/why-would-advanced-alien-warships-be-manned-rather-than-drones?noredirect=1#comment147437_52605) that "manned" wouldn't technically be correct when talking about an extraterrestrial spacecraft:

> By definition, they wouldn't be 'manned', but they might be 'aliened'.

Potential jokes aside, is there a more species-neutral adjective we can use here?

Comment: Related: [Word for requiring a crew](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35945/word-for-requires-a-crew)

Comment: When looking at news stories, the first story to show up in ABC television networks list of "manned space flight" is about the successful return of a monkey. http://abcnews.go.com/topics/news/science/manned-space-flight.htm

Comment: When I saw the title, I thought the complaint would be that women are left out.

Comment: I have heard a suggestion which I am not interested enough to verify that the word "manned" in this context actually comes from the French "main" (pronounced man) meaning hand, and has nothing to do with the gender or indeed species of the crew. If that etymology is correct, then Manned is just fine.

Comment: @JosephRogers Interesting.

Comment: I thought so, as I say I haven't verified it in any way, hence it's a comment rather than an answer

Comment: @JosephRogers I tried to search for it now. Could find no evidence. AFAICS, the etymology is simply from "man".

Comment: @JosephRogers definitely true of "manual" (as in manual labour, manual operation). I always laugh at the ignorance of those who insist that the word "manual" be replaced with a "gender-neutral term".

Comment: @JosephRogers I am not certain how you pronounce "man", but I am pretty sure it is far from how "main" is pronounced in French. The sound represented by "ain" is nasal and has no equivalent in English.

Comment: @njzk2 they are pretty similar when pronounced by an average British English speaker, but that may say more about the quality of my French accent than it does about the correct French pronunciation. The point I was trying to make is that it's a short sound like man in manual rather than the longer English word main

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254086/alternative-for-manning-a-station) is possibly related. Some people consider "manned" as gender-neutral, you could also possibly treat it as species-neutral (this is debated in comments to that question, not everyone agrees). Alternatively, some of its answers might also be suitable for your question.

Comment: @Bruno But the argument there is that "manned" comes from "human", right? So how could it be species-neutral?

Comment: @Fiksdal I guess it depends on what you consider a "person". I'd suppose much of the evolution of the use of words related to "man"/"Man" in a gender-neutral way has more to do with making the difference between humans and (other) animals, with various attributes that humans have (e.g. more advance intelligence). It's likely that your alien pilots have some for of intelligence at least equal to that of humans. The choice of term may be partly "political", i.e. whether you choose to give those creatures personae and so on...

Comment: @Bruno While I think the word 'person' could certainly be applied to an intelligent extraterrestrial individual, I think the word "human" could not. Since the etymology noted in the argument you referred to is 'human' or 'man' rather then 'person', I don't think I get the reasoning when applied to extraterrestrials. I only get it when applied to female humans.

Comment: @nigel222 agreed: "manual" being rooted in the Spanish word "mano" which means "hand" (not "male" or "man"). For example, "mano a mano" means "hand to hand" not "man against man"

Comment: @Fiksdal: *Man* is not the same word as *human*. // *Manual* is from Latin *manus* "hand".

Comment: @Cerberus Do you mean that as an addition to the above discussion?

Comment: @Fiksdal: ...yes?

Comment: @Cerberus I see. Didn't really read very thoroughly the discussion Bruno linked to, just saw the comment there by Matt.

Comment: @Fiksdal: Oh, the only discussion I have seen is the one in the comments above. I haven't clicked on any links.

Comment: @Cerberus Right. Bruno was basically suggesting that "manned" may work for extraterrestrial ships.

Comment: @Fiksdal: I think it might: it could be argued that the word has been sufficiently "unmanned" and generalised from its origin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46713/discussion-between-fiksdal-and-cerberus).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Consider ***[crewed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/crew?q=crewed#crew__12)***, which means:

> Provide (a craft or vehicle) with a group of people to operate it:
>
> '*normally the boat is crewed by 5 people*'.

It works perfectly in a sci-fi context. For example,

> The ship was ***crewed*** primarily by Vulcans and cyborgs.

Comment: *Raises eyebrow* Fascinating, Captain.

Comment: Note that NASA only uses *crewed*, never *manned*.  Bonus: it's unambiguously gender-neutral.

Comment: "Bonus: it's unambiguously gender-neutral" Indeed, we have little knowledge about alien genders

Comment: @gerrit Wait.... The obvious interpretation of this is that, *NASA secretly is employing aliens*, and NASA doesn't want to offend them.

Comment: @gerrit, WHAT DO YOU KNOW AND WHO ARE YOU WORKING FOR?!!

Comment: @Silenus You should be careful saying things like that! It is *for whom are you working*.

Comment: You are not cleared for that information.

Comment: "*The ship was crewed primarily by Vulcans and cyborgs.*" -> clicks link -> "crew: 2.2 informal, chiefly US, A group of rappers, breakdancers,".  Yes, this.

Comment: Silenus: Well, I have done some research into this @gerrit , and [I have uncovered](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/60896/) that he is a high-ranking member of something called "Area 51". I think this might answer the question of how he knew and who he is working for. Although he might already have breached his non-disclosure agreement by telling us the part about what NASA does.

Comment: @Fiksdal legal or illegal aliens?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I'm only going to deport the illegal ones. Trust me.

Comment: Neil Armstrong was the first astronaut to walk on the moon. Now spell "Neil A." backwards. Did we send him to the moon or did we send him *back*?

Answer (score 42):

**[Piloted](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/piloted)** would seem to fit nicely, although it does have to connotation of having a pilot rather than just a passenger.

**[Staffed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/staffed?s=t)** could also work if you didn't want to talk about a specific pilot rôle.

**[Operated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/operated?s=t)** would also take out the species element of the word, focusing on the job.

Comment: I feel _Operated_ does not necessarily imply any sentience on the craft itself; a drone is operated.

Comment: Indeed - something can be operated remotely, eg from a control centre on Earth.

Comment: Off-topic: I haven't seen "rôle" written with a circumflex for years! Cool

Comment: @PaddyLandau, that's one of he delights of EL&U, you find all sorts of sad grammar nerds who like to use those sorts of things. I felt that since the circumflex is [tailing out in France](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-35496893), I'd better keep it alive in English. #JeSuisCirconflexe

Comment: Piloting and operating both sound like things that could happen remotely, or by smart/well-programmed machines.  Though staffed does sound like it would imply a staff with which the staffing was accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

**Occupied** would do the job:

One of the meanings of **occupied** is:

> Being used by someone; with someone in it.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occupied)

> The craft was **occupied**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/196794)

Comment: @P.O. It does attempt to provide an answer - I don't believe it is a comment at all.   Pedro is saying that he thinks the a suitable word is "occupied".

Comment: the comment is pre-written when you flag and answer, it'S for the second part that I chose this flag  "provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker." An answer without sources, references and/or links are incomplete, hence requires clarification. Add it and I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: @P.O. Just FYI, you can actually edit the pre-written comment soon after its posted. :)

Comment: We appreciate the desire to help, but please consider either expanding your answer or deleting it. We're looking for long answers that provide explanation and context. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed. [(more¹)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post) [(more²)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/lots-of-not-always-useful-but-well-intentioned-answers)

Comment: This is in fact a far better choice than crewed because it may be operated by computer and have only scientists on board.

Comment: Pedro, I have edited your answer as suggested in my previous comment. It is now safe from deletion. However, in the future, please use this as an example so that other people don't have to edit your posts.

Comment: "Occupied" makes it sound like a hostile takeover (e.g. a foreign army occupying a country; the 'occupy Wallstreet' movement taking over ordinary road use'). If the text said "*the ship was occupied by Klingons*" I would assume the Klingons had taken it by force. It does work as a word to convey that there are lifeforms in the ship, but it carries some other meanings that make me think it's not a good fit for an alternative to the word 'manned'.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Yes, this is absolutely correct.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - As in: The toilet was **occupied** for a long time while clearing out some **Klingons**.

Comment: You say occupied, you hear a toilet!

Comment: @HannoverFist It's interesting, because toilets are (typically) occupied without a hostile takeover, but for some reason the word "occupy" implies a takeover when applied to larger region.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

**Inhabited**

What are commonly called 'drones' are sometimes called '[uninhabited air vehicles](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=uninhabited%20air%20vehicle)' as unmanned also means 'cowardly' so is not a selling point for combat aircraft; the inverse of this would be inhabited.

Most UAVs are piloted remotely or autonomously, so 'piloted' does not imply inhabited - the [Reaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-9_Reaper) is piloted, the [V1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-1_flying_bomb) was not, neither was inhabited. Similarly, in military speech, UAVs also have a crew - if you are the remote pilot or weapons control for a UAV you are still considered its air crew, and every UAV also has a ground crew:

> The primary concept of operations, remote split operations, employs a
>   launch-and-recovery ground control station for take-off and landing
>   operations at the forward operating location, while the crew based in
>   continental United States executes command and control of the
>   remainder of the mission via beyond-line-of-sight links. [USAF MQ-9 Reaper fact sheet](http://www.af.mil/AboutUs/FactSheets/Display/tabid/224/Article/104470/mq-9-reaper.aspx)

Comment: Nice idea, but your reference to UAV seems misguided: a [quick google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=uav) suggests that it most commonly is used as an initialisation of ***unmanned** air vehicle*

Comment: @AndyT yes, that's why I said 'sometimes' and linked a google search showing plenty of uses. Even this http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US20080027647 uses unmanned rather than uninhabited :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly leave anthropocentrism behind, you have to think outside of the...ugly bags of mostly water. Otherwise you are making assumptions that are echoes of that anthropocentrism.

> The Greebbllaapp vessel originally ***consisted of*** several semi-sentient modules that wandered desultorily around the galaxy extracting iridium, but its frighteningly malign intelligence did not fully emerge until the assembly became ***infested with*** quintillions of mutated nanomachines.

Whether or not the greebllaapp can be considered 'living species' or not is debatable...But if you must talk about a 'major interstellar war' going on between biologicals, then one of the combatants might well say their enemy's ships are 'infested'.

Comment: These are words for drones?

Comment: Aren't they, though?

Comment: Yeah, but the questions doesn't mention drones, it's talking about living "species".

Comment: Aren't they, though?  Seriously, I'm not convinced your parameters make sense.  Look up the phrase 'Calling a rabbit a smeerp'.

Comment: Right, but can these words also be used for all living species?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? Anyway, you have two perfectly conventional answers with lots of upvotes, and you haven't accepted either yet.

Comment: I'm not saying they wouldn't be. It was not a rhetorical question. I was actually asking you. I am not familiar with the terms, and English is not my native language.

Comment: I don't think "infested" is a suitable word as a non-human substitute for "manned".   "infested" does not bring with it the sense that the infestation is the original crew - in fact, it implies occupation by an infestation that is unwelcome and not the original purpose of the vessel.

Comment: To a combatant, the enemy is unwelcome. Again, if OP wants a conventional answer, there are perfectly good ones he can accept. Because of the rabbit/smeerp thing, 'manned' is a perfectly good answer too.  This discussion has begun to be about angels dancing on pins.  So I'm done commenting

Comment: In star trek the motion picture, the antagonist initially refers to the Enterprise as being "infested" with "carbon units" ie humans, whose purpose it does not understand